# Square brackets instead of curvy brackets

Tags: brackets

I have the following example:

```
\begin{equation}
\[ 
\left \{
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
  1 & 5 & 8 & a \\
  0 & 2 & 4 & a \\
  3 & 3 & -8 & a 
  \end{tabular}
\right \}
\]
\end{equation}
```

It should be a matrix, so I would like to have proper square brackets. I have tried the approach with setting them manually (`\Bigg[`) but the matrix is going to be larger so it needs to be set automatically. In the code above, I tried to use:

```
 \[ 
\left \[
```

but it didn't work. 
Any idea what's not working in the previous code?

Comment: `\left[` and `\right]`. The characters `{` and `}` are special, so the must be escaped for getting printed braces, but `[` and `]` aren't special. However, with the package `amsmath` you can simply type ``\begin{bmatrix} 1& 5 & 8 & a \\...\end{bmatrix}``.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many expanding delimiters available in TeX/LaTeX; the main ones are (round) parentheses, (square) brackets and braces. The only problematic ones among them are the braces, because `{` and `}` are special characters, used for grouping and for delimiting arguments.

So, `\left(...\right)`, `\left[...\right]` and `\left\{...\right\}` are the “automatically expandable versions. The same for the manual `\bigl(`, `\bigl[` and `\bigl\{`; similarly for `\bigr` and the other commands in the same family.

The commands `\[` and `\]` mean a totally different thing: they delimit an unnumbered math equation.

So your case should be (with `array`, not `tabular`):

```
\begin{equation}
\left[
  \begin{array}{cccc}
  1 & 5 & 8 & a \\
  0 & 2 & 4 & a \\
  3 & 3 & -8 & a 
  \end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
```

but upon loading `amsmath` you have a wealth of better constructions:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 5 & 8 & a \\
  0 & 2 & 4 & a \\
  3 & 3 & -8 & a 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```